# Google earth flight path

Tags: google-earth

I have a polyline defined on google earth. I want to create a flight path along the polyline so that I can create a video of how the topography changes along the polyline. Does anybody know how to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tutorial](http://serc.carleton.edu/eyesinthesky2/week9/using_google_earth.html#follow_path) that describes how to make a Google Eath tour that follows a path.